# Existence of angle functions on the proper open subsets of $S^1$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-numbers, smooth-manifolds

Here is the problem 1-8 in Lee's introduction to smooth manifolds:

> > An angle function on a subset $U \subset S^1$ is a continuous
> >     function $ \theta: U\to \mathbb R$ such that $e^{i\theta(z)}=z$ for all $z \in U$. Show that there exists an angle function on an open subset $U\subset S^1$ if and only if $U \neq S^1.$ For any such  angle function, show that $(U,\theta)$ is a smooth coordinate chart for $S^1$ with its standard smooth structure.

I wonder if $U\ne S^1$ is sufficient for the existence of such a continuous angle function(I feel that the statement should be "*there exists an angle function on an open subset $U\subset S^1$ if and only if $U$ is not dense in $S^1.$*").

Let's take a special case when $U=S^1-\{-1\}$. Suppose there is such a continuous angle function $ \theta: U\to \mathbb R$ such that $e^{i\theta(z)}=z$ for all $z \in U$. Then we must have $\theta(z)=arg(z)+2k\pi$. However, It seems that there will always be a "jump" somewhere on the circle making $\theta$ discontinuous. For example, if we define $\theta(z)=\arg(z)$, then when $z$ approaches $-1$ from the first quadrant and the four quadrant separately, $\theta(z)$ approaches to $\pi$ or $-\pi$.(This argument turns out to be **wrong**, see the answers and comments given below by repliers)

Since professor Lee doesn't make any corrections to this problem, it should be correct as given. But how to define such a continuous angle function for arbitrary proper open subset of $S^1$? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning that $\arg$ isn't a continuous function on $S_1\setminus \{-1\}$ is not correct. Your argument is that it is not because $\lim_{z\rightarrow -1}\theta(z)$ does not exist, however, for something to be continuous on $S_1\setminus \{-1\}$, it is not necessary that this limit exist. It is merely necessary that, for any $y\in S_1\setminus\{-1\}$ we have that $\theta(y)=\lim_{z\rightarrow y}\theta(y)$ - and this does hold for the argument function.

Note that once you've found that $S_1\setminus \{-1\}$ admits an angle function, it is not hard to find an angle function for any set of the form $S_1\setminus \{z\}$ for any $z\in S_1$ just by conjugating your previous function with a rotation taking $z\mapsto -1$, and any proper open subset of $S_1$ is a subset of some $S_1\setminus \{z\}$.

Comment: Thank you! I have realized my mistake~~~

Answer (score 4):

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow S^1; \quad x \mapsto e^{ix}$.

If there exists such an angle function, then $U$ can't be $S^1$: if it were, we would have that $f \circ \theta =Id_{S^1},$ hence $\theta$ is an injection. Since it is a continuous injection in a compact set, it is a homeomorphism with its image (which is a closed interval by preservation of connectedness and compactness), but this can't happen (why?).

If $U$ is not $S^1$, there exists a point which is not in $U$, let it be $p$. Consider $f^{-1}(\{p\})$. This is a set of equidistant points, with distance $2\pi$. Take a point $a \in f^{-1}(p)$, and consider $f|_{(a,a+2\pi)}$
. $f$ is easily verified to be a homeomorphism* with $S^{1} \backslash \{p\}$. Take now $\theta:=f|_{(a,a+2\pi)}^{-1}$. We have that $\theta|_U$ satisfies what you want.

*One can argue directly, by computing what is $f$ and $f^{-1}$, but also can argue indirectly as follows: $f|_{(a,a+2\pi)}$ is continuous, since it is the restriction of a continuous function. By considering an exhaustion of $(a,a+2\pi)$ by compact sets, it is clear that the restriction of $f$ to any of those compact sets is a homeomorphism. Since the images of those compact sets will also create an exhaustion of the image, $f|_{(a,a+2\pi)}$ must be a homeomorphism.

---

OBS: By exhaustion, I mean a sequence of compact sets such that $K_n \subset \text{int} K_{n+1}$.

---

Proving the lemma:

> Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces, where $Y$ is Hausdorff, such that $X$ has an exhaustion by compact sets $K_n$, and let $F:X\rightarrow Y$ be a continuous bijective map such that $F(K_n)$'s exhaust $Y$. Then $F$ is a homeomorphism.

*Proof*:

$F$ is by hypothesis continuous, and being injective on compact sets (the codomain is Hausdorff), each $F|_{K_n}$ is a homeomorphism with its image. We will prove that $G:=F^{-1}$ is continuous.

Take $y \in Y$, together with a open neighbourhood $W$ of $G(y)$. Since $K'_n:=F(K_n)$ exhaust $Y$, there exists a $K'_N$ such that $y \in K'_N$. By hypothesis, $y \in \text{int}K'_{N+1}$. Due to our previous observation, $G|_{K'_{N+1}}$ is a homeomorphism. Therefore, $G|_{\text{int}K'_{N+1}}$ is continuous (in fact, a homeomorphism). Hence, there exists an open neighbourhood $V$ of $y$ such that $G(V) \subset W$. But a neighbourhood in the induced topology of an open set must be an open set in the topology itself. Hence, we found an open neighbourhood of $y$ which is taken inside $W$. This proves continuity of $G$.

Comment: And by your definition, $\theta(e^{ix}):=f|_{(0,0+2\pi)}^{-1}(e^{ix})=x$. But $\theta(e^{i\frac{1}{n}})\to \frac{1}{n}$ while $\theta(e^{i (2\pi - \frac{1}{n})})\to 2\pi- \frac{1}{n}$.  We need $\theta(z)$ to be continuous.

Comment: By exhaustion, I mean that $K_n \subset \text{int}K_{n+1}$. Note that your counterexample does not satisfy this.

Comment: And in your second comment, the sequence $e^{i \frac{1}{n}}$ does not converge, nor does the other one, since $(1,0)$ is not on the domain (I assume you are talking about this case). So, there is no issue.

Comment: Sorry, could you be more explicit? I didn't understand what you are saying.

Comment: Note the part "Since the images of those compact sets will also create an exhaustion of the image". The problem in your case is on the image.

Comment: You mean $F(K_n)=\{ 0,1,1/2,\dots, 1/n \}$ doesn't exhaust the image $\{0,1,1/2,\dots \}$?

Comment: Yes. Note that $0 \notin \text{int}F(K_1)$, but $0 \in F(K_0)$.

Comment: It seems that you are using such a lemma in the last paragraph:
Let$X,Y$ be topological spaces such that $X$ has a exhaustion by compact sets $K_n$, and let $F:X \to Y$ be a continuous map such that $F(K_n)$'s exhaust $Y$, if each $F|K_n$ is a homeomorphism, then $F$ is a homeomorphism. Could you prove it or show me some reference for this in your solution? Thank you!

Comment: Let me restate my example here. I wonder if that argument works even when we assume that  $K_n \subset \text{int}K_{n+1}$.
Let $F:\{0,1,2,\dots\} \to \{0,1,1/2,\dots\}$ such that $F(0)=0, F(n)=1/n$.
 Let $K_n=\{ 0,1,2,\dots, n \}$, then $K_n \subset \text{int}K_{n+1}$ because $\{ 0,1,2,\dots \}$ is discrete. The restriction of $F$ to $K_n$ is a homeomophism from $K_n=\{ 0,1,2,\dots, n \}$ to $\{ 0,1,1/2,\dots, 1/n \}$, but $\{ 0,1,2,\dots \}$ and $\{ 0,1,1/2,\dots \}$ are not homeomorphic(The former one is noncompact).

Comment: I've edited and added the lemma with some differences from your enunciation. Please tell me if any issues arise.

Comment: What would be an explicit expression of $f^{-1}$? Would we have to resort to working with $\operatorname{atan2}$ (or something comparable), or is there a nicer way?